# Parameter filter SSRS Expression Dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression

I have a dataset created from an expression that takes parameters from 3 other datasets.

I need to add a parameter to this that allows the user to input a value, and then the dataset will add that value to the where clause to filter the results displayed. If the value "Any" is input then the results will be unfiltered for this section of the Where clause (If that makes sense).

I wrote this and added it to the expression Where clause, but it is not working.

```
+ IIf(Parameters!RCode.Value = "ANY", "", " AND h.rcode = " + Parameters!RCode.Value + " ")
```

I can provide the rest of the where clause if it is needed, but if i remove this line, the whole thing works, if i add this line, it bombs out with

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Cannot set the command text for dataset 'DS'. (rsErrorSettingCommandText)
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL for the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

In the dataset query you can use parameter names by simple prefixing them with @ eg. @RCode

To make it work, your WHERE clause should be look like (I assume your column name is rcode):

```
WHERE .... 
AND (@RCode = 'ANY' OR rcode = @RCode )
```

For multivalue parameters

```
WHERE ...
AND ('ANY' IN (@RCode) OR rcode IN (@RCode) )
```

Comment: Because this is an expression, I ended up needing to create a hidden parameter for the @RCode dataset, and then another parameter that feeds this dataset/ parameter. so basically I had 2 parameters feed a dataset, which was then passed to the main dataset. If this was purely SQL, and not dynamic or even an expression, then your code would have worked. When I was purely doing reports within SSMS I do things how you posted all over the place, but thats not the case anymore, SSRS is just annoying.